# ACF - Template Assignment Seems Permanent

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've been using the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) (ACF) plugin for quite a while now.  It's absolutely awesome but I'm experiencing some behaviour that is not the norm.

I've noticed that if I change the page template that is assigned to a set of custom fields, the pages that ran off that template (no longer assigned to those fields) effectively holds onto those custom fields and thus renders correctly on the site.

E.g.

ACF Partner Fields are assigned to a Partners Template that has a number of pages running of it.

If I assign these fields to another template, all of the pages running of the Partners template, still render correctly.

I'm not sure I've ever experienced that before and it is causing issues with another plugin that is being integrated for translation.

Any ideas what might be happening?

All time and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the template, your only changing where those fields appear on the backend and what post type or location they write to in the database. The database table for those unassigned posts still contains the information form those ACF, they just won't be written to any longer.